# Rails 3: how to use active record and mongoid at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I read alot that folks recommend using nosql together with sql datastores. For example have some reporting audit-trailing or log information in mysql and some threaded hierarchical data in mongodb.

Is it possible to hook up rails with active record on mysql as well as mongoid?

Out of the box it seems not to work...Any hints?
Or is this a not recommended approach?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, to do it, you're supposed to leave Rails intact, so don't exclude libraries like it's commonly suggested in Mongoid documentation. You need to configure them separately, so you need to have a database.yml and mongo.yml config files and you need to make sure they're both getting loaded.

After that, you can enable/disable AR and Mongoid on a per-model basis.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #this is an AR model
end

class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  #this is a Mongoid model
end
```

Comment: Have to create the mysql first even if I don't use them... after that it works like you discribed, thanks!.... One thing tho... after configuring mongoid rails generators work only with documents, does it mean I have to generate models for AR manual?

Comment: I'd say yes, but it'd be worth investigating whether you can generate either successfully. I'll take a look and you can too. http://mongoid.org is a good starting place.

Comment: The Mongoid gem overrides the `orm` generator in Rails, but you should be able to reset it by adding something like this to your application.rb: `config.generators {|g| g.orm :active_record}`