# Does anyone know of a sample Rails project with Mongo AND MySql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have Googled this pretty extensively over the last few hours. We're in the process of trying to configure a new project and we were thinking of using Mongo to power our mapping data and other read-only, speed-dependent queries, while the rest of our application data would be better served in a relational db.

(Keep in mind I am a bit of a NoSql noob, we are just reacting to what we are familiar with)

I'd love to know how well these work together in Rails and even how best to set it up. I found this [Using different connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404620/using-rails-migration-on-different-database-than-standard-production-or-devel), but there are a few other suggested methods.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why use stay using sql and save the read-only data in memcached or any other caching mechanism.

Comment: It's certainly possible to use multiple data stores in the same application, as long as you aren't expecting cross-DB magic like joins.  See: [Rails 3: how to use active record and mongoid at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411283/rails-3-how-to-use-active-record-and-mongoid-at-the-same-time).