# ActiveRecord and NoSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nosql

I've been working with Rails for a few years and am very used to ActiveRecord, but have recently landed a task that would benefit from (some) NoSQL data storage.

A small amount of data would be best placed in a NoSQL system, but the bulk would still be in an RDBMS. Every NoSQL wrapper/gem I've looked at, though, seems to necessitate the removal of ActiveRecord from the application.

Is there a suggested method of combining the two technologies?

Comment: what makes you say that? `ActiveRecord` can live very happily, ignoring any other gem... can you give an example gem which "necessitates the removal of ActiveRecord from the application"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411283/

Comment: @UriAgassi CouchPotato (see Github page, Ctrl-F Activerecord) and MongoDB("The important thing here is to avoid loading ActiveRecord.") are the two I looked at this afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what NoSQL service you are looking into, but we have used MongoDB in concert with Postgres for a while now.  Helpful hint, they say you need to get rid of ActiveRecord, but in reality, you don't.  Most just say that because you end up not setting up your database.yml and/or running rake commands to setup AR DB.

Remember also that Postgres has HStore and JSON datatypes which give similar functionality as NoSQL datastores.  Also, if the data you are looking to store outside of your AR DB is not very complex, I would highly recommend looking into Redis.

Comment: Seems as if, as you say, this is more over-zealous documentation than anything else. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Well, if you are only using, for example, MongoDB, and you do not properly configure AR (database.yml), AR will through back a bunch of errors when you attempt to run the Ruby process.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-omniauth-mongoid/blob/master/Gemfile.lock) of this [project](https://github.com/Raindal/rails4_mongoid), you can see that it uses ActiveRecord with Mongoid.

Even if you use other gems that don't need ActiveRecord, you shouldn't care. If you are using it, you should have a valid reason to do so.